# Sequence of operations in $x += --$x;

Tags: c#, php

In "C#"

```
int x = 35;
x += --x;
```

will outputs 69

same expression in "PHP"

```
$x = 35;
echo $x += --$x;
```

will outputs 68

Please explain why, and point to some docs for this topic
Thanks

Comment: `--$x` is 34. 34 + 34 is 68.

Comment: What a surprise not everything in the world is working the same way ...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: ^ is a doc you need to read before asking.